# CMake dependency target does not exist

Tags: build, configuration, compiler-errors, cmake, dependencies

I have the following script to build one of my projects

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.0.2)
INCLUDE(ExternalProject)
SET(PROJECT_NAME Khronos)
PROJECT(${PROJECT_NAME})
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")
SET_DIRECTORY_PROPERTIES(PROPERTIES EP_PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/library-build)

FIND_PACKAGE(sphinxbase)
if (${SPHINXBASE_FOUND})
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SPHINXBASE_INCLUDE_DIR}/sphinxbase/)
else ()
    ExternalProject_Add(
        sphinxbase
        GIT_REPOSITORY      "https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinxbase.git"
        GIT_TAG             "e34b1c632392276101ed16e8a05862e43f038a7c"
        SOURCE_DIR          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/sphinxbase
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/sphinxbase/autogen.sh
        BUILD_COMMAND       make
        UPDATE_COMMAND      ""
        INSTALL_COMMAND     make install
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE     ON
        LOG_DOWNLOAD        ON
        LOG_UPDATE          ON
        LOG_CONFIGURE       ON
        LOG_BUILD           ON
        LOG_TEST            ON
        LOG_INSTALL         ON
    )
    ExternalProject_Get_Property(sphinxbase SOURCE_DIR)
    ExternalProject_Get_Property(sphinxbase BINARY_DIR)
    SET(SPHINXBASE_SOURCE_DIR ${SOURCE_DIR})
    SET(SPHINXBASE_BINARY_DIR ${BINARY_DIR})
    SET(SPHINXBASE_LIBRARIES ${SPHINXBASE_BINARY_DIR}/src/libsphinxbase/.libs/libsphinxbase.a)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SPHINXBASE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
endif ()
SET(DEPENDENCIES ${DEPENDENCIES} sphinxbase)
SET(LIBS ${LIBS} ${SPHINXBASE_LIBRARIES})

FIND_PACKAGE(pocketsphinx)
if (${POCKETSPHINX_FOUND})
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${POCKETSPHINX_INCLUDE_DIR}/pocketsphinx/)
    add_definitions( -DMODELDIR="/usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model")  # TODO: more portable
    SET(DEPENDENCIES ${DEPENDENCIES} pocketsphinx)
else ()
    ExternalProject_Add(
        pocketsphinx
        DEPENDS             sphinxbase
        GIT_REPOSITORY      "https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx.git"
        GIT_TAG             "0d41af2efe3f77a3e7f22a54e42684bb1562876d"
        SOURCE_DIR          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/pocketsphinx
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/pocketsphinx/autogen.sh --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR> --with-sphinxbase=${SPHINXBASE_BINARY_DIR}
        BUILD_COMMAND       make
        UPDATE_COMMAND      ""
        INSTALL_COMMAND     make install
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE     ON
        LOG_DOWNLOAD        ON
        LOG_UPDATE          ON
        LOG_CONFIGURE       ON
        LOG_BUILD           ON
        LOG_TEST            ON
        LOG_INSTALL         ON
        )
    ExternalProject_Get_Property(pocketsphinx SOURCE_DIR)
    ExternalProject_Get_Property(pocketsphinx BINARY_DIR)
    SET(POCKETSPHINX_SOURCE_DIR ${SOURCE_DIR})
    SET(POCKETSPHINX_BINARY_DIR ${BINARY_DIR})
    SET(POCKETSPHINX_LIBRARIES ${POCKETSPHINX_BINARY_DIR}/src/libpocketsphinx/.libs/libpocketsphinx.a)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${POCKETSPHINX_SOURCE_DIR}/include/)
    add_definitions( -DMODELDIR="${POCKETSPHINX_BINARY_DIR}/model")
    SET(DEPENDENCIES ${DEPENDENCIES} pocketsphinx)
endif ()
SET(LIBS ${LIBS} ${POCKETSPHINX_LIBRARIES})

FIND_PACKAGE(PortAudio)
if (${PORTAUDIO_FOUND})
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PORTAUDIO_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    SET(DEPENDENCIES ${DEPENDENCIES} PortAudio)
else ()
    ExternalProject_Add(
        PortAudio
        SVN_REPOSITORY      "https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/portaudio/portaudio/trunk/"
        SVN_TRUST_CERT      1
        SOURCE_DIR          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/PortAudio
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/PortAudio/configure --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR>
        BUILD_COMMAND       make
        UPDATE_COMMAND      ""
        INSTALL_COMMAND     make install
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE     ON
        LOG_DOWNLOAD        ON
        LOG_UPDATE          ON
        LOG_CONFIGURE       ON
        LOG_BUILD           ON
        LOG_TEST            ON
        LOG_INSTALL         ON
    )
    ExternalProject_Get_Property(PortAudio SOURCE_DIR)
    ExternalProject_Get_Property(PortAudio BINARY_DIR)
    SET(PORTAUDIO_SOURCE_DIR ${SOURCE_DIR})
    SET(PORTAUDIO_BINARY_DIR ${BINARY_DIR})
    SET(PORTAUDIO_LIBRARIES ${PORTAUDIO_BINARY_DIR}/lib/.libs/libportaudio.dylib)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PORTAUDIO_SOURCE_DIR})
    SET(DEPENDENCIES ${DEPENDENCIES} PortAudio)
endif ()
SET(LIBS ${LIBS} ${PORTAUDIO_LIBRARIES})

FIND_PACKAGE(LibSndFile)
if(${LIBSNDFILE_FOUND})
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${LIBSNDFILE_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    SET(DEPENDENCIES ${DEPENDENCIES} LibSndFile)
else ()
    ExternalProject_Add(
        LibSndFile
        URL                 "http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/files/libsndfile-1.0.26.tar.gz"
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/LibSndFile/configure --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR> --disable-external-libs
        BUILD_COMMAND       ${MAKE}
        SOURCE_DIR          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/LibSndFile
        UPDATE_COMMAND      ""
        INSTALL_COMMAND     make install
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE     ON
        LOG_DOWNLOAD        ON
        LOG_UPDATE          ON
        LOG_CONFIGURE       ON
        LOG_BUILD           ON
        LOG_TEST            ON
        LOG_INSTALL         ON
    )
    ExternalProject_Get_Property(LibSndFile SOURCE_DIR)
    ExternalProject_Get_Property(LibSndFile BINARY_DIR)
    SET(LIBSNDFILE_SOURCE_DIR ${SOURCE_DIR}/src)
    SET(LIBSNDFILE_BINARY_DIR ${BINARY_DIR})
    SET(LIBSNDFILE_LIBRARIES ${LIBSNDFILE_BINARY_DIR}/src/.libs/libsndfile.a)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${LIBSNDFILE_SOURCE_DIR})
    SET(DEPENDENCIES ${DEPENDENCIES} LibSndFile)
endif ()
SET(LIBS ${LIBS} ${LIBSNDFILE_LIBRARIES})

# TODO: create FindTritium.cmake
ExternalProject_Add(
    tritium
    GIT_REPOSITORY  "https://github.com/syb0rg/tritium.git"
    GIT_TAG         "f6cd6a750945373b48c05c0f2d682e478e6a719d"
    SOURCE_DIR      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/tritium
    UPDATE_COMMAND  ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND make install
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE ON
    LOG_DOWNLOAD    ON
    LOG_UPDATE      ON
    LOG_CONFIGURE   ON
    LOG_BUILD       ON
    LOG_TEST        ON
    LOG_INSTALL     ON
)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(tritium SOURCE_DIR)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(tritium BINARY_DIR)
SET(TRITIUM_SOURCE_DIR ${SOURCE_DIR})
SET(TRITIUM_BINARY_DIR ${BINARY_DIR})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${TRITIUM_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
SET(TRITIUM_LIBRARIES ${TRITIUM_BINARY_DIR}/libtritium.a)
SET(LIBS ${LIBS} ${TRITIUM_LIBRARIES})
SET(DEPENDENCIES ${DEPENDENCIES} tritium)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(include)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(src)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJECT_NAME}
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:audio>
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:util>
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:main>
        )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBS})
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${DEPENDENCIES})
```

When run, it gives me the following output:

```
$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 7.3.0.7030029
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 7.3.0.7030029
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Doxygen: /usr/local/bin/doxygen (found version "1.8.11") 
-- Found sphinxbase: /usr/local/lib/libsphinxbase.dylib  
-- Found pocketsphinx: /usr/local/lib/libpocketsphinx.dylib  
-- Found Portaudio: /usr/local/lib/libportaudio.dylib
-- Found LibSndFile: /usr/local/lib/libsndfile.dylib  
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:189 (ADD_DEPENDENCIES):
  The dependency target "LibSndFile" of target "Khronos" does not exist.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:189 (ADD_DEPENDENCIES):
  The dependency target "PortAudio" of target "Khronos" does not exist.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:189 (ADD_DEPENDENCIES):
  The dependency target "pocketsphinx" of target "Khronos" does not exist.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:189 (ADD_DEPENDENCIES):
  The dependency target "sphinxbase" of target "Khronos" does not exist.


-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/syb0rg/Dropbox/Development/Khronos/Khronos/build
```

Doing research on these errors didn't turn up any results. What is causing these errors in my script?  What should I change to fix them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command

```
find_package(<libname>)
```

doesn't define CMake **target** `<libname>`.

You need to move appendings

```
SET(DEPENDENCIES ${DEPENDENCIES} ...)
```

to corresponded `else` clauses, which defines appropriate targets with `ExternalProject_Add`.

Comment: This doesn't work, when I try building my program it tries building parts that rely on other (unbuilt) parts, resulting in an error.

Comment: [mcve] please. You have relatively long `CMakeLists.txt` with repeated parts, and some part is fail. It is unclear which part is fail.

Comment: It is a complete and verifiable example.  I just now edited out some irrelevant parts of the script to help minimize it.  I'm not sure what you mean by repeated parts, the ExternalProjects may look the same but all are their own separate component.

Comment: I meant similar parts. Yes, "repeated" word is not suitable for that, sorry for that. When you built your code from similar blocks, normally only the first one should be elaborated, and other can be simply copied (with appropriate replacement). You write `it tries building parts that rely on other (unbuilt) parts, resulting in an error.` - which **exact** part is failed to build, and what (unbuilt) part it relies on?

Comment: The issue with it failing seems to be elsewhere, and this answer seems to have gotten me past this initial issue.

Comment: I stumbled upon this error and was confused before realizing that the dependency target was not being built because I forgot to update my root CMakeLists.txt by adding a `add_subdirectory(my_dependency_dir)`.